# How to Freeze and Unfreeze a checkbox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, cell

I want to "freeze" the cell after clicking the box. The statement i want to have in the cell doesn't work. I always get runtime error 1004, the error is the If-statement. Here the code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    
    If Range("H1").HasFormula Then 
        Range("H1").Value = Range("H1").Value
        Me.CheckBox1.Caption = "Unfreeze"
   Else
        Range("H1").Formula = "=IF(Sheet2!E1 = 12;Sheet2!E1;"")"//If value in E1 is 12, H1 = 12 otherwise the cell stays empty 
        Me.CheckBox1.Caption = "Freeze"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, change `"=IF(Sheet2!E1 = 12;Sheet2!E1;"")"` with `"=IF(Sheet2!E1 = 12;Sheet2!E1;"""")"` the necessary double quotes must be escaped with another one for each... In order to check the resulted string, try using `Debug.Print "=IF(Sheet2!E1 = 12;Sheet2!E1;"""")"`. If it looks as you need, in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G` being in VBE), it is the correct string...

Comment: In Immediate window there is the correct output, but when I click on the box I still get the error and the ` Range("H1").Formular=IF(Sheet2!E1 = 12;Sheet2!E1;"""")" ` is yellow highlighted

Comment: Please replace ";" with comma (","). Even if your regional settings require semi colon in the sheet formula, VBA should write it with the standard list separator (comma).

Comment: Ah, thanks, how do I close this question?

Comment: No need to close it. The above comments will maybe help somebody else. The main goal of the community is to make people learning...

Comment: @Beluga you can add the working code as an answer along with what changes you made to get it working, you can then mark this question as answered.

Comment: The code you show us was supplied by me lake an answer at your previous question. You asked that time for a formula like "=J2", if I remember well. I will post an answer with the whole correct working code for the new request. No need to mark it as accepted answer. Just comment something to show that the code works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in the next way, please:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    
    If Range("H1").HasFormula Then 
        Range("H1").Value = Range("H1").Value
        Me.CheckBox1.Caption = "Unfreeze"
   Else
        Range("H1").Formula = "=IF(Sheet2!E1 = 12,Sheet2!E1,"""")" 
        Me.CheckBox1.Caption = "Freeze"
   End If
End Sub
```